# Thinktecture IdentityManager vs IdentityServer

Tags: authentication, thinktecture-ident-server

Looking at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683732/Thinktecture-Identity-Server-Configuration-Customi and http://brockallen.com/2014/04/09/introducing-thinktecture-identitymanager/ , I am a bit confused about the relation between IdentityServer and IdentityManager.

The way I currently understand it is the following:

- IdentityServer can be used as an STS, and to manage users.
- IdentityManager can be used to manage users.

Are the above statements correct? Will the users-part be phased out of IdentityServer in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure IdentityManager is intended to be the GUI for IdentityServer v3+. Therefore, there won't be one built in, as in previous versions.

Comment: Exactly, Identity Manager is used to manage the users on the database. You can create/edit users. Then, those users are able to identify using identityserver v3.

Dixit from github:IdMgr is a modern replacement for the ASP.NET WebSite Administration tool that used to be built into Visual Studio. It is meant to be a tool for developers and/or administrators to manage the identity information for users of their applications. This includes creating users, editing user information (passwords, email, claims) and deleting users.

[link](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityManager)

Comment: The answer makes sense, but what confuses me as that there seems to be 2 similar constructs using each:

            appBuilder.UseIdentityServer(options);

and

            appBuilder.UseIdentityManager(new IdentityManagerConfiguration()
            {
                IdentityManagerFactory = factory.Create
            });

My guess is that UseIdentityManager will in fact call UseIdentityServer

Answer (score 3):

Dominick Baier (one of the authors of IdentityServer) posted this when announcing version 3:

> while designing IdentityServer v3 we realized that we really also need a good solution for managing users, identity, claims etc – and that this should be ideally a separate project – so I’d also like to announce Thinktecture IdentityManager

You can read whole blog post [here](http://leastprivilege.com/2014/04/09/announcing-thinktecture-identityserver-v3-preview-1/).

I don't know if users-part will be phased out of IdentityServer. The state now is that version 3 does not have GUI administration yet and all configuration is done in code. I am quite sure that Dominick and Brock Allen will eventually implement some web GUI for administration of idsrv but you should ask them maybe by opening a new issue [here](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3/issues).